# Is there a way to dynamically reference sheet names in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot

seeing the way my current question trends I don't think this one will earn a lot of merit points. admittedly, this is a "I'm lazy of doing repetitive tasks and want to automate it" kinda question

Question: is there a way to dynamically have the pivot update its target range to the active worksheet and not the last sheet you copied it from?

my goal is to get something like

```
=activesheet!$a$1:$b:$2
```

why I'm asking this question: I never really liked pivot tables, always thought they were a waste of time, but since my boss likes them and doesn't like vba, I gotta conform and use the dumb pivots.

really not sure what kind of other materials or proof of research you guys want with this question, but i did try to search on my own and found nothing. if theres anything else you guys want just ask. Thx

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use INDIRECT in the Pivot Table source, so as far as I know this isn't possible without VBA.

Comment: interesting figured as much but thought perhaps there was something i didn't know of. thx. at the least, i know not to waste too much time on this

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so please don't complain for putting it in here ;-)

There is something which could ease the pain when updating the data source after pasting the pivot table into a new workbook:

If the Pivot Table does not refer to a range but to an Excel table instead (cf. Ribbon -> Insert-Tab -> Table), then you will just need to remove the file name in the data source without updating the range (because there is no range, just the table name)